# Универсальная структура БД

Tags: php, mysql

Хотел написать универсальный каркас для веб приложений, но столкнулся с проблемой проектирования БД. Задумка в следующем:
Есть категории, типы, элементы(ноды). Ноды могут быть любого типа и относится к любой категории. У ноды может быть связь с дочерними элементами. Например: нода типа "город", включает в себя ноды с типами "улица" и "река". Не соображу как построить базу для таких отношений.

Comment: а какую БД используете?

Comment: `У ноды может быть связь с дочерними элементами.` Ну дерево. `Ноды могут быть любого типа и относится к любой категории.` Ну атрибуты. Всё просто и плоско... откуда проблемы-то?

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидным решением является использование [Документ-ориентированной СУБД](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL). Если же задача требует использования именно [Реляционной СУБД](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%A1%D0%A3%D0%91%D0%94), то логичным решением, на мой взгляд, будет реализация Документ-ориентированной схемы в контексте Реляционной СУБД.

Для этого можно использовать следующую модель:

[image: Модель хранения данных]

Соответственно каждая конкретная Нода (Node) это запись в таблице Node, определяющая только имя класса, который будет использоваться для инкапсуляции данных при загрузке из базы. Таблица Value, в свою очередь, содержит не только данные типа "Свойство - Значение", но и ссылку на Ноду, к которой эти данные относятся, а так же идентификатор объекта.

Остается реализовать только загрузчик, который будет соответствовать следующей семантике:

```
interface ObjectRepository{
  public Entity find(id, Entity);
}
```

Реализовать это не сложно, но нужно помнить, что решение довольно "тяжелое", так как лишено плюсов Реляционной и Документ-ориентированной СУБД. К счастью, качественный слой абстракции позволит всегда оптимизировать структуру такой БД перенеся часть сущностей в отдельные таблицы.

Answer (score 1):

В Drupal сделано похожим образом. Только там node это посты, а вот taxonomy - это термины которые можно структурировать parent->child. 
Еще отдельно табл для настроек типа key->value

Answer (score 0):

Сделать две таблицы.

В первой хранить все узлы:

```
node_id|node_name
1      |City
2      |Street
3      |River
4      |House
5      |Fish
```

Во второй обозначать связи

```
child_id|parent_id
2       |1
3       |1
4       |2
5       |3
```

Answer (score 0):

вопрос должен изначально состоять не в структуре базы. вы сначала в теории проработайте ваши обьекты, какие у них будут свойства и т.д. Потом будете думать как составить модель данных. Иначе у вас получится бред и ущербная модель данных в базе. 
Иначе говоря структура базы должна отражать взаимосвязь моделей объектов системы в рамках мировоззрения бд.

На текущий уровень вашего вопроса вам достаточно 2 таблицы. В одной список нодов - такие таблицы называют справочники. и вторая - связь между нодами (колонка код нода, колонка кому подчиняется). Но поверьте опыту, с текущим подходом в дальнейшем возникнут проблемы.